# Populate field based on value within a field in another table

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, cursor, update, search

I have two datasets: `dat_1` and `dat_2`. 
I would like to populate `field_1` in `dat_1` based on values within `field_1` in `dat_2`. I don't know if i need it, but they have `ogr_ID` field in common, with the same values in both tables.

i'm trying with this script but the the tool is populating `field_1` in `dat_1` with the same value for all the rows, and it's also printing always the same value.

```
fc = r"path/dat_1"
tbl = r"path/dat_2"
field = "field_1"

s_cursor = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(tbl, field)
for row in s_cursor:
    load = row[0]

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, field) as u_cursor: 
    for row in u_cursor: 
    row[0] = load
    u_cursor.updateRow(row)
    print (row)

del row 
del u_cursor
```

Comment: Add a screenshot showing both tables

Comment: Your program logic sets the `load` variable as many times as there are rows in the SearchCursor, then uses the last value in every row of the UpdateCursor, so it's behaving exactly as it should.  If you want different behavior (perhaps updating by common key?), you'll need to state what it is that you want to do (and, ideally, attempt to do it)

Answer (score 3):

Create a [Dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) using da.SearchCursor, then update:

```
import arcpy

fc = r"path/dat_1"
tbl = r"path/dat_2"
common_id_field = "ogr_id"
valuefield = "field_1"

d = {ogrid:value for ogrid,value in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(tbl, [common_id_field, valuefield])}

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, [common_id_field, valuefield]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row[0] in d:
            row[1] = d[row[0]]
            cursor.updateRow(row)
```

(When you do:

```
s_cursor = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(tbl, field)
for row in s_cursor:
    load = row[0]
```

load will only be last row in tbl)

Comment: Thanks, i tried and i had no error, but `field_1` is still the same as before, it's not changing. I tried to print `d` : within i have only 4 items, so 8 values , also if my `tbl` contains thousands of records. is it normal?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot showing both tables?